# Google maps geocode api return no results when using 'liverpool' searchTerm

Tags: google-geocoding-api

We are using the geocode api in order to retrieve a list of results, containing address components and  geometry (coordinates of that address). Whenever we are using ‘liverpool’(could also be with one or more capital letters) as a search term, we are receiving an empty result list, where it should have contained the details from above, filled with appropriate data. If we are inserting another relevant term, suffix or prefix with ‘liverpool’ then the result list is no longer empty. Also, replacing ‘liverpool’ with any other city/postcode would work perfectly (e.g 'london').
Request: **maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=liverpool&region=gb&key={}**

Response: **{
"results": [],
"status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}**

Any idea if it's something wrong with the geocode or with this specific address ?

Comment: Hi Simion, I've spotted the same issue. Most likely it's some problem with this specific address on Google side as it's also not working on their official Geocoding demo page.
I've opened an bug report, hopefully they'll resolve that shortly: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229908260